# Online repositories of scanning electron microscope photographs?

Tags: microscopy

I have looked at every single Wikimedia commons photo in the category 'scanning electron microscope'. Unfortunately, I could not find any other repositories of such photos, but I would readily look at every single photograph there as well. It strikes me that such repositories are also bound to be useful to biologists and biology students. A simple Google search did not yield much. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Are you looking for images for your personal use, CC or similar licensed images or commercial photos? =)

Comment: @Rory i'm looking for anything and everything. what people have posted so far is great.

Comment: micrographs, not photographs. Photons are not involved in the generation of SEM micrographs (well, they CAN be for some techniques, but those are afaik mostly used to study certain mineral deposits etc.).

Answer (score 12):

First off I'd like to reccomend the University of Dartmouth's publicly available collection located [here](http://remf.dartmouth.edu/images/).  They have both SEM and TEM images of a wide range of organisms and cells from algae to see urchins through everything from cholera to mammalian cells.  Images are high quality, fully captioned and properly attributed.

I'm a little confused as to the problem you're having with google - see my original comment on your question.  However I have looked at the photos of Wikimedia Commons in the SEM category and see that they are either images taken with, images of SEM Microscopes or technical drawings regarding their function.  I assume that you're looking for the images taken with SEM.

I was able to find a great number of similar images to those in the commons with a Google Image search - I read above that you were having problems with this approach so perhaps try the search term "[SEM images](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rls=en&q=SEM%20images&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=M7j8TsS6I4OO8gPNkOjgAg&biw=1440&bih=728&sei=Nbj8ToPlFsnh8AOn-KnBAQ)" in image search (or [this search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SEM%20images%20-wikimedia&hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=k7r8TumaLMLJ8gPKssXUAQ&ved=0CCEQsAQ&biw=1440&bih=728) to avoid duplications from images you have already seen on Wiki Commons)?

Examples found on just the first page:
[image: Mushroom Spores (Uni. Dartmouth]
[image: Ash Grain (USGS) - not biological but interesting nonetheless]

Comment: thanks for those recommendations. the trouble with google image search is that it doesn't search everything, doesn't know about everything -- and how can it? not everything has top-down categorically descriptive text attached. there's just no way to find out about repositories of images like the ones linked to here without asking people.

Comment: I know exactly where you're coming from, hope Dartmouth helped though =)

Answer (score 10):

David Orloff's [The Cell – an Image Library](http://www.cellimagelibrary.org/) has [thousands of SEM images](http://www.cellimagelibrary.org/images?advanced_search=Advanced+Search&image_search_parms%5Bbiological_process%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bcell_line%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bcell_type%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bcellular_component%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bfoundational_model_anatomy%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bhuman_dev_anatomy%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bhuman_disease%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bidentity_bim%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bimage_mode_bim%5D=scanning+electron+microscopy+%28SEM%29&image_search_parms%5Bitem_type_bim%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bmolecular_function%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bmouse_gross_anatomy%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bmouse_pathology%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bncbi%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bparameter_imaged_bim%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bplant_growth%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bpreparation_bim%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bprocessing_history_bim%5D=&image_search_parms%5Brelation_to_intact_cell_bim%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bsource_of_contrast_bim%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bteleost_anatomy%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bvisualization_methods_bim%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bxenopus_anatomy%5D=&image_search_parms%5Bzebrafish_anatomy%5D=&k=&page=1).

Comment: very nice. i have a hard time deciding whether or not i like the dartmouth images better or i like the cell images better, and that's an excellent predicament to be in.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at:

- [XTALENT Image Gallery](http://www.xtalent.com.au/gallery/thumbnails.php?album=2), more than 600 images, last updated in 2006, though.
- [Dennis Kunkel Microscopy, Inc.](http://www.denniskunkel.com/), "scientific stock photography library of light microscope pictures and electron microscopy images featuring science and biomedical microscopy photos".
- [Iowa State University SEM library](http://www-archive.mse.iastate.edu/microscopy/tutorials.html), includes pictures submitted by students from around the state of Iowa.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at my website which has a section called Images.  http://www.hssemgroup.com/
There are more than 13 sites listed which have hundreds of SEM images posted

Comment: Specifically http://www.hssemgroup.com/students-enjoying-their-sems/resource-urls - looks like a very helpful resource.